# Reference a variable from another file

Tags: ansible

I have a play

```
---
  - hosts: all 
    name: Full install with every component

    gather_facts: no
    
    roles:
      - oracle_client
      - another_role
      - and_so_on
```

where each of the roles has a dependency on a single `common` role which is supposed to load all vairable I will require later:

```
  - name: Include all default extension files in vars/all and all nested directories and save the output in test
    include_vars:
      dir: all
      name: test
  
  - debug:
      msg: "{{test}}"
```

the `common` role folder structure has

```
common
  vars
    all
      ansible.yml
      common.yml
      oracle_client.yml
```

where `common.yml` specifies a `app_drive: "D:"` and then `oracle_client.yml` tries to do `oracle_base: "{{ app_drive }}\\app\\oracle"`

At runtime I get

```
fatal: [10.188.27.27]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'app_drive' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '<ansible-project-path>/roles/common/tasks/main.yml': line 18, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - debug:\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Per [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html) "the files are sorted alphabetically before being loaded." so I was expecting to have access to a varible from another file? How should I do this instead?

TLDR;
I want to to load all my variables from one place but have them logically splits (I went for separate files) but cross reference the splits. How is that best done?

Comment: Looks like it works as I expect it to and in my example above it is the 

```  - debug:
      msg: "{{test}}
```

part that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works as I expect it to and in my example above it is the

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{test}}
```

part that fails.